# Where is the `torch.empty` defined?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

(I am not a Python veteran so pardon me if this is a naive question.)

Following the [PyTorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/tensor_tutorial.html), below code works fine.

```
import torch
x= torch.empty(5,3) # <========= HERE
print(x)
```

But the Visual Studio Code complains that:

> E1101:Module 'torch' has no 'empty' member

Eclipse PyDev has a similar warning.

So I use below code to check what `torch` offers:

```
for (k, v) in torch.__dict__.items():
    print(k, v)
```

And I find that it is a built-in:

```
empty <built-in method empty of type object at 0x00007FFA380E0A80>
```

Since it is a method, I searched all the `*.py` file in the torch package folder for something like `def empty` and `empty`, no luck.

So where is this `empty` method defined? Some pyd/DLL?

How is it imported into the namespace?

Or put it another way, how to create a built-in function for my own package?

### ADD 1 -- 10:38 AM 11/12/2018

Extending Python Built-ins with C/C++

https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html

I guess it's the `torch::empty` method. I have found [a lot of matches](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/search?l=C%2B%2B&p=1&q=torch%3A%3Aempty) in the github PyTorch codebase. But I haven't nailed the definition yet.

Comment: Probably written in C++ - maybe this helps a bit:
https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/where-does-torch-c-come-from/2015